# SQL - How to get employees who are absent for a specific date range

Tags: sql

I have Employees and Timecard tables. When an employee clicked the "time in" button the datetime (UTC) will be saved in the Timecard table. I can already retrieve employees using the following query:

```
SELECT emp.id, emp.Firstname, emp.Lastname
FROM Employees emp
WHERE emp.Id NOT IN (SELECT ti.EmployeeId 
                     FROM TimeCards ti
                     WHERE ti.[Date] BETWEEN '2018-04-22 16:00:00' AND '2018-04-23 15:59:00')
```

However the problem is, I also need to include the datetime from the Timecard table so the output should be: EmployeeId, Firstname, Lastname, TimeCardDate. Also, I need to fetch records by date range (e.g April 19 - April 23)

Can you help me find solution on this? Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: I just need to retrieve the employees who are absent for a specific date range. Currently in our system, it will only save a record in the Timecard table when you click "Time In". It will store the EmployeeId, TimeCardDate, TimeIn, TimeOut. All datetime are in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join:

```
SELECT e.id, e.Firstname, e.Lastname, t.TimeCardDate
FROM Employees e JOIN TimeCards t
     ON e.id = t.EmployeeId
     AND t.[Date] NOT BETWEEN '2018-04-19 16:00:00' AND '2018-04-23 15:59:00'
```

Comment: Thanks @iagooa , however I need to retrieve the employees who are "Absent"

Comment: I have corrected the query with the denial. Try it and tell me!

Comment: It is not retrieving the employees who are absent for a specific date :(

Answer (score 0):

A I understand your question, you want to join the two tables, to get the employees and their "time ins". Something like the following should do.

```
SELECT emp.id,
       emp.Firstname,
       emp.Lastname,
       ti.Date
       FROM Employees emp
            INNER JOIN TimeCards ti
                       ON ti.EmployeeId = emp.Id
       WHERE ti.Date BETWEEN '2018-04-22 16:00:00' AND '2018-04-23 15:59:00';
```

Comment: Thanks @sticky-bit, however I need to retrieve the employees who are "Absent"

Comment: When they are absent in that period of time there won't be any dates in the time card table for that period I'd guess. So there's nothing to display, or is there?

Comment: There will be dates if someone logged in for a specific date. It won't just save if an employee didn't logged in. Here's the fields in my Timecard table (EmployeeId, TimeCardDate, TimeIn, Timeout). The datetime is in UTC

Comment: Left Join will do. Please look at my answer below.

Comment: I tried it and just retrieving the employees who are logged in not the absent

Comment: @Eugene: I'm still confused. Do you maybe want the dates of the "time ins" that are not within a certain period from those employees who were absent in that period? Are are there any dates indicating  absence in your time card table and you want those?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a LEFT JOIN, which will bring all the records of the employee table and the matching records of the time in time out table. So what happens is you will get NULLS for the employees who where absent.

```js
SELECT 
 e.id, e.Firstname, e.Lastname, t.TimeCardDate
FROM 
 Employees e 
LEFT JOIN 
 TimeCards t ON e.id = t.EmployeeId
WHERE
 t.Date BETWEEN '2018-04-22 16:00:00' AND '2018-04-23 15:59:00'
```